# SQL - Dynamic Attributes

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I am trying to create a database of items where each item can have multiple attributes. I also have a table of containers (containers can hold items). Each container has multiple required attributes. The item attributes must meet the requirements of the container attributes in order for the item to fit into the container.

Note: new attributes can be added at any time.

```
Example:
Item 1 Attributes
    Color: Red
    Material: Aluminum
    Length: 100
    Width: 200
    Rating: 4

Container 1 Required Attributes:
    Color=Red
    Material=Aluminum
    Length<105
    Width<300
    Rating=4
```

I want to find all items that fit into a container. If the Container Required Attributes table has a field for comparator, I can get all required attributes for container 1 then dynamically generate a query based on the comparator field. I am not a database expert but this does not seem to be a good design.

Another option would be to have multiple Container Required Attributes tables - one for maximum value, one for minimum value, one for equal value numeric, one for equal value string, etc.

```
Example:
Container 1 Maximum Attributes
Length: 105
Width: 300

Container 1 Minimum Attributes
<none>

Container 1 Equal Attributes (Float)
Rating: 4

Container 1 Equal Attributes (String)
Color: Red
Material: Aluminum
```

In this case, I don't have to dynamically generate queries but this doesn't seem like the best solution either because I will eventually need tables for >= and <=.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better design?

Comment: Is “`Steel`” less than “`Wood`”, or are ordering constraints only required on numeric properties?

Comment: Ordering constraints are required only for numeric properties. Numeric properties can be <, >, <=, >=, ==, or !=. All other values can be == or !=.

Answer (score 1):

when you say this:

> Note: new attributes can be added at any time

That carries a whole lot of consequences.  SQL as originally developed, was not intended to support what I'll call a "dynamic data model".  The discovery of a new but missing attribute in the data model was occasioned by only one of two events:  a change in the information requirements or a discovery of an error or omission in the current implementation.  Dynamic data modeling isn't necessarily a bad thing, but if you acheive it by throwing out a lot of the discipline that comes with classical database management, you throw out the corresponding guarantees at the same time.

If you go one step further, and say that any user can add a new attribute as well as add new data, there are even more consequences.  Two users may discover the same attribute, and give it different names.  This results in the "synonym problem".  Two users may discover two different attributes but give the same name to both.  This results in the "homonym problem".  If you leave these problems unresolved, making sense out of the resulting data is going to be nearly impossible.

I'm going to remind you of two differences that are important with regard to adding new attributes to an existing database.  At the SQL level, it's the difference between DDL and DML.  At the data level, it's the difference between metadata and data.  You may know most of this, but it's worth reconsidering in the light of dynamic modeling.

In a classical database, the way you implement a newly discovered attribute of an existing entity or relationship among entities, is by a construct like

```
alter table X add column Y ....
```

This is DDL.  The right to perform DDL is typically limited to DBAs and not granted to users that provide data or use applications as an interface to provide data.  So the model is not dynamic in that sense.  And the DBA community (if there's more than one DBA) confers with each other before altering the model.

When you do something like adding a column to an existing table, two things happen.  First, the structure of the actual table is altered to accomodate the new column.  Second, the data dictionary is updated to reflect the alteration of the table.

The data diciotnary contains metadata, data that describes a model of the database itself.  User tables contain data, which describes the subject matter.

Generally, when you try to implement dynamic modeling in SQL,  you end up storing copies of metadata (like column names) in user tables.  It becomes your responsibility to maintain the correlation between this user data and the actual data structures, or their reflection in the data dictionary.

You can do this.  But it's a whole lot of work.  And you are embarking on a journey where SQL may not be the best way to get where you're going.

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters can only be expressions, not identifiers (columns) or operators, so the only way to avoid generating queries dynamically would be to have a fixed set of attributes and comparisons for all containers, and store only the values:

```
Container 1 Required Attributes:
  Color: Red
  Material: Aliminum
  Max_Length: 105
  Max_Width: 300
  Rating: 4
```

If different containers have different number or types of requirements, your queries must be dynamic anyway.
In that case, having multiple required attributes tables does not appear to have any benefit over a single table.

If the attributes are stored in columns, you could make the design even more dynamic by storing a single string that you plug into the `WHERE` condition, like `items.color='Red' AND items.Length<105 ...`. This has the downside that you have to store the conditions separately if you want to be able to change some condition later without parsing that string.